# Primary Key issue in apache Phoenix

Tags: apache, primary-key, apache-phoenix

I have a table of 8 columns where 'employee' is a primary key in that table. When I am trying to retrieve the rows using primary key, I am not getting any results even there is data in the table.

Here is My query:

```
select * from employees_table where employee = '1028'
```

The table has a record of 1028. when I am trying to retrieve using primary key , I am getting empty results. Why I am getting empty results? It works when I tried to use other columns but not working with the primary key. Please explain me the reason. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information. Post some Elixir code here.

Comment: code is in python and framework is python apache phoenix.                 
`import phoenixdb <br />
database_url = 'http://ph.icrid.com:8765'  <br />
connection = phoenixdb.connect(database_url, autocommit = True)  <br />

cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=phoenixdb.cursor.DictCursor)  <br />
query = "SELECT * from employees_table where employee='1028'"  <br />
cursor.execute(query)  <br />
result = cursor.fetchall()  <br />

Comment: You've posted it with `phoenix-framework` tag initially. Other tags are not in my area of interest, sorry.